# What's the simplest and fastest way to send messages between two NodeJS processes?

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, rabbitmq, ipc

I have two processes, process A, that collects information from a feed, does some calculations and outputs some data to process B, which consumes that data.

Process A probably sends around 50 messages per second to process B. I don't require all messages to reach process B.

I currently have process A running as a web server and process B subscribes as a websocket client to process A. This feels pretty hacky and I feel like there's probably a better solution out there.

I know of various messaging queues such as RabbitMQ and Pub/Sub models like Redis Pub Sub, but it feels like a) I'm over-engineering things and adding a layer of complexity and b) this will probably slow down the time it takes messages to reach process B.

Is there a better solution out there that is faster than having one process run as a local webserver for another process? Is there anything wrong with what I'm currently doing?

Comment: Are the two processes completely distinct? Or maybe process A can spawn process B? I didn't tested the speed of the "direct" communication between paternt and child process but can be interesting

Comment: In project I have used [cote](https://github.com/dashersw/cote) which uses socket under the hood but i found it pretty amazing.

Comment: @AndreaFranchini I'd like to keep them distinct, just because they do completely different things and in future I'd like the option to swap out process B for other things.

Comment: @maksbd19 This looks very interesting - will check it out, thanks! I guess it looks a bit similar to [node-ipc](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc)

Comment: Are the necessarily on the same machine? if so, is it a POSIX machine (unix / linux / macOS, etc')? - If the answer to both is "yes", consider using Unix sockets for the communication (that's what I use for facil.io and it's a very common solution).